# "I like mum who cooks for me." Is this sentence logically correct?

Tags: word-usage

This sentence is from a children's song (written by non-native English speaker) below:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that it might not be logically correct?

Comment: There's a comma missing. It should be "I like mom, who cooks for me". Without the comma it looks like it could ambiguously also admit something else missing as in "I like a mom who cooks for me" or "I like the mom who cooks for me", which are less logical in that they suggest a choice of moms. I would say it's a punctuation error but if you don't know that it can look like a logic error.

Comment: It's only a punctuation error where such rules are rigorously expected. In lyrics, rules are relaxed a lot, which doesn't matter if there is no loss of clarity. The pause expected before a non-specifying relative clause in standard prose would kibosh the cadence required by the lyrics. // Some might even object to the comma splices here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for adult-erating the lyrics for a children's song.

Comment: The presence or absence of a comma is not a foolproof guide to the status of the relative clause.

Comment: The original question is about it logical correctness, not about punctuation. It needs clarification.

Comment: It's 'logical correctness' is dependent on whether it is a wrongly punctuated relative clause.